# How do we say the name of a people plurally?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number

I am writing an essay and I came across an event to describe in which I have to name the whole population of Spain doing something. Do I say"the Spanishes" or "the Spanish"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a long list of national nicknames, historical and otherwise:

***Spaniards***: Spanish people

***Danes***: Danish people

***Yankees***: American people

***Canucks***: Canadian people

***Aussies***: Australian people

***Poles***: Polish people

**Swedes**: Swedish people

And so forth. None of the above are considered offensive at this point in history. There is, to be sure, a much longer list with national nicknames that *are* regarded as offensive, which is why I'm not including it here.

Comment: Some of these terms are colloquial, utterly unsuitable for OP's purpose of writing an essay. Also, whether all Spanish people are Spaniards is highly debatable.

Answer (score 1):

You would say "the Spanish" - similarly for British, Irish, French, Chinese. However, you would say "Italians", Hungarians, Latvians, Kenyans. I'm not sure there is a rule for which form you say for which nationalities, although you might detect a pattern in the examples I have just written. 
In most contexts you may find that it is preferable to use a form like "the Spanish people"; it can sound less harsh in a sentence.

Comment: You could also say *the Spaniards* - it really depends on the exact meaning in context.

Comment: Does the Spanish people sound more "literary" than the Spanish all-short? I'm sort of trying to make my vocabulary stand out even though I'm not a native English speaker.

Comment: The *Swedes* and the *Poles* do not fit your -n pattern

Comment: Poland and Sweden don't end in vowel sounds. That was more the pattern I was sensing with the -n suffix; I wasn't proposing anything prescriptive.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a ***[Demonym](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonym)***.  The Oxford Dictionaries defines ***[demonym](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/demonym)*** as:

> *A noun used to denote the natives or inhabitants of a particular country, state, city, etc.*

There are both official and informal ones as well as offensive ones.  (For example, while you can call people from the USA *Yanks*, the official name is *Americans*.)

Wikipedia generally lists the demonym for each country in the general facts sidebar.  For [Spain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spain), one person is a *Spaniard* and collectively, they're the Spanish.